# I'm having trouble with foreign-key in Knex.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

Im try to insert data on my database with Knex.JS, in some tables I have a foreign key, and I guess the trouble is occurring with this part of project.

I'm having this error message:

```
error: insert into "classes" ("cost", "subject", "user_id") values ($1, $2, DEFAULT) - null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

MY knexfile:

```
import {resolve} from 'path'

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      database: "XXXX",
      user: "XXXX",
       password:"XXXXXXX"

    },
    migrations: {
      directory: resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations')
    }
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true
};
```

and the migrations im using:

```
import Knex from 'knex'

export async function up(Knex: Knex) {
    return await Knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
        table.increments('id').notNullable().primary();
        table.string('name').notNullable();
        table.string('avatar').notNullable();
        table.string('whatsapp').notNullable();
        table.string('bio').notNullable();
    })
}


export async function down(knex: Knex) {
    return await knex.schema.dropTable('users')
}
```

> 

```
import Knex from 'knex'

export async function up(Knex: Knex) {
    return await Knex.schema.createTable('classes', table => {
        table.increments('id').notNullable().primary().unique();
        table.string('subject').notNullable();
        table.decimal('cost').notNullable();


        table.integer('user_id').
        notNullable().
        references('id').
        inTable('users').
        onDelete('CASCADE').
        onUpdate('CASCADE')
    })
}


export async function down(knex: Knex) {
    return await knex.schema.dropTable('classes')
}
```

I guess the trouble can occur i the moment of insert data to as some data depend of other data:

```
async  store(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const {name,
            avatar,
            whatsapp,
            bio,
            subject,
            cost,
            schedule
            } = req.body
    
            const trx = await knex.transaction()
    
           try {
    
            var created_user = await trx('users').insert({
                name,
                avatar,
                whatsapp,
                bio
            })
    
            var user_id = created_user[0]
           
           
    
            const insertedclassesID = await trx('classes').insert({
                subject,
                cost,
                user_id
            })
```

I've got do this with SQLite3, but not with Postgres.
I have to change the ORM Knex to Sequelize for Exemple?

I know is a lot of questions But i'm needing help!

THANKS FOR HELP ME!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you cannot insert a null value for 'user' in the table "classes".

You can fix this depending on the functionality you want.

If the users column in the classes table MAY be null, then change your migration:

```
table.integer('user_id').
    defaultTo(null).
    references('id').
    inTable('users').
    onDelete('CASCADE').
    onUpdate('CASCADE')
```

else if the users column should always have data, then check if your user id is being assigned correctly

```
var user_id = created_user[0]
```

I believe that line should be replaced by:

```
var user_id = created_user[0].id
```

but can't say without running it.